# Weapons related tags - which ones?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have some questions related to gun control/gun rights/weapons on the site, and will likely get many more.

What would be good tags for them (and how many do we need?)?

Ideally, the tag(s) would be objective and balanced.

Some of the possibilities are:

- [firearms](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firearms)

  The main flaw is that it's not very specific, and lumpts together questions related to military weapons and war; and civilian weapon ownership; and police weapons tactis (tasers etc... - I recall seeing a taser question recently but it may have been on Skeptics).
- [gun-control](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gun-control)

  The downside is that this is somewhat partisan, as it's the term that IMHO is used with a connotation that the less guns the better. I could be wrong on the connotation though.
- [gun-rights](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gun-rights)

  This one is loader the other way from gun-control; it has a connotation that guns should NOT be restricted.
- [civilian-weapon-ownership](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilian-weapon-ownership)

  The pro is that it is 100% guaranteed to be neutral and objective. The con is that it's an unaesthetic mouthful. Personally, I'm inclined towards this one unless people hate it.

Answer (score 4):

There's been exactly one question about guns / firearms / personal weaponry so far. To which you added three more or less synonymous tags.

I would say wait until there are sufficient questions to gauge the need before trying to guess at it.

Also, I retagged that question.

Comment: I added 3 tags since I didn't know which one was most appropriate. That's why I asked this question :)

Comment: @DVK: just pick the most appropriate one, or (as in this case), *create* the most appropriate one. A tag with a single question is borderline useless anyway, so unless / until there are more questions on the same general topic it doesn't really *matter* what the tag is called.

Comment: Based on Skeptics, I would anticipate it to be a reasonably frequently used tag.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of tags is to separate questions into knowledge pools, n an attmpt to help experts find questions that they can answer. With that in mind, the tags you should use is whatever word most people would use to find a question. The best answer is to wait until enough questions exist to come to some sort of conclusion. Additional tags can become synonyms and link to the most popular tag. Tags that are not used more than once are automagically deleted from the database.

Answer (score -1):

My own suggestion would be a combination of two tags:

- [military-weapons](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/military-weapons)

  For questions pertaining to weapons use by the military, M.I.C, etc...
- [civilian-weapon-ownership](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilian-weapon-ownership)

  For questions pertaining to political debates over the rights and restrictions on civilian weapon ownership. It seems 100% neutral and objective, compared to gun-rights or gun-control.

I don't think we need a separate tag for police weapons/tasers etc... yet.

Comment: Why didn't you just create this tag instead of adding 3 to the *one* question about guns on the site?